# Is it okay to defer exception handling to a single function for a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, exception

I am writing a class in Python and part of the code deals with a server. Therefore I need to deal with exceptions like ExpiredSession or ConnectionError.

Instead of writing exception handling code for every try/except block, I have a single function in the class to deal with the exceptions. something like this (inside the class definition)

```
def job_a(self):
    try:
        do something
    except Exception as e:
        #maybe print the error on screen.
        self.exception_handling(e)

def job_b(self):
    try:
        do something else
    except Exception as e:
        #maybe print the error on screen.
        self.exception_handling(e)


def exception_handling(self,e):
    if isInstanceOf(e,ExpiredSession):
        #deal with expired session.
        self.reconnect()
    if isInstanceOf(e,ConnectionError):
        #deal with connection error
    else:
        #other exceptions
```

I am not sure if this kind of code would cause any problem because I haven't seen code do this. like, possible memory leak? (Now I notice the memory usage grows(though slowly) when I have more and more error/exception and eventually I have to restart the process before it eats all my memories). Not sure this is the cause.

Is it a good practice to pass exceptions to a single function?

Comment: I don't think it's good practice. It makes your code much harder to read, for one, and it's harder to handle unanticipated exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers).  You can see some examples of using context managers for error handling [here](http://dietbuddha.blogspot.com/2012/12/52python-encapsulating-exceptions-with.html).  The [contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator allows you to write context managers concisely in the form of a single function.  Here's a simple example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def meth1(self):
        with self.errorHandler():
            1/0

    def meth2(self):
        with self.errorHandler():
            2 + ""

    def meth3(self):
        with self.errorHandler():
            # an unhandled ("unexpected") kind of exception
            ""[3]

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def errorHandler(self):
        try:
            yield
        except TypeError:
            print "A TypeError occurred"
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print "Divide by zero occurred"
```

Then:

```
>>> x = Foo()
>>> x.meth1()
Divide by zero occurred
>>> x.meth2()
A TypeError occurred
```

The `with` statement allows you to "offload" the error handling into a separate function where you catch the exceptions and do what you like with them.  In your "real" functions (i.e., the functions that do the work but may raise the exceptions), you just need a `with` statement instead of an entire block of complicated try/except statements.

An additional advantage of this approach is that if an unforeseen exception is raised, it will propagate up normally with no extra effort:

```
>>> x.meth3()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#394>", line 1, in <module>
    x.meth3()
  File "<pyshell#389>", line 12, in meth3
    ""[3]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

In your proposed solution, on the other hand, the exception is already caught in each function and the actual exception object is passed the handler.  If the handler gets an unexpected error, it would have to manually reraise it (and can't even use a bare `raise` to do so).  Using a context manager, unexpected exceptions have their ordinary behavior with no extra work required.